# Forge viewer: setNavigationLock does not work properly in BimWalk mode

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

If setting the navigation lock when in BimWalk mode, mouse gestures in the viewer seem to take effect when the navigation lock is deactivated. This does not happen in orbit mode.

Steps to reproduce:

- Open a model, e.g. at https://lmv.ninja.autodesk.com/
- Enable First Person mode (BimWalk)
- In the debugging console, call `NOP_VIEWER.setNavigationLock(true)`
- Do a dragging gesture in the viewer. Nothing moves, as expected.
- Call `NOP_VIEWER.setNavigationLock(false)`
- The view moves, seemingly according to the last mouse gesture that was made.

I assume this is not expected behavior? Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, I've been able to reproduce the issue. Good catch! Let me report the issue to the engineering team, and please stay tuned for updates on the [changelog](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7) to see when the issue is fixed.

Comment: I see this has been fixed now, in version 7.58. Thanks!